# Crear un array de grupos y ids relacionados con los grupos

Tags: python

Quiero crear un array, un diccionario o una DataFrame (cualiquier sea la forma) que contiene los id agrupados por grupo de los subscriber que son en el mismo grupo.

Los ids estan en una DataFrame `side_subscriber.index`, el output de este array esta :

```
Int64Index([160, 161, 296, 306, 365, 386, 471], dtype='int64', name=u'subscriber_id')
```

Los grupos estan en un `numpy.ndarray` que se llama `indexResultat` :

```
[1 1 0 0 1 1 1]
```

Intento hacer lo siguiente sin saber como iniclializar el array agrupando por grupo :

```
kernelGroup = []
i = 0
for idx in indexResultat:
    print "idx : ",idx
    i = i+1
    print kernelGroup
    for kernel in kernelGroup:
        print "kernel : ",kernel
        if idx == kernel:
            print "we have the group ",kernel 
            print kernel
            # anadimos el id
            kernelGroup = kernelGroup[kernel].append(side_subscriber.index[idx])
            break
    # no habemos el grupo
    print "we don't have the group", idx
    #kernelGroup = kernelGroup.append(kernelGroup,[idx,side_subscriber.index[idx]])
    kernelGroup = kernelGroup.append([idx,side_subscriber.index[i]])

print kernelGroup
```

Y obteno :

```
idx :  1
[]
we don't have the group 1
idx :  1
None

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-a0add6c15d78> in <module>()
      5     i = i+1
      6     print kernelGroup
----> 7     for kernel in kernelGroup:
      8         print "kernel : ",kernel
      9         if idx == kernel:

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

El output que espero esta

```
{0:[296, 306], 1:[160, 161, 365, 386, 471]}:
```

---

Sé que esta función hace mas o menos lo que quiero hacer :

```
def cluster_points(X, mu):
    clusters  = {}
    for x in X:
        bestmukey = min([(i[0], np.linalg.norm(x-mu[i[0]])) \
                    for i in enumerate(mu)], key=lambda t:t[1])[0]
        try:
            clusters[bestmukey].append(x)
        except KeyError:
            clusters[bestmukey] = [x]
    return clusters
```

Comment: Marine ¿Lo que esperas al final es algo como: `{0:[296, 306], 1:[160, 161, 365, 386, 471]}`?

Comment: @FJSevilla Si !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dependiendo de si necesitas más o menos eficiencia puedes hacerlo de muchas formas (con Pandas, NumPy o con Python estándar solamente). Una muy simple es mediante Pandas y `DataFrame.groupby`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Simulamos tus datos de orígen
df = pd.DataFrame(index=[160, 161, 296, 306, 365, 386, 471])
grupos = np.array([1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1])

res = pd.DataFrame({'ids': df.index, 'grupos': grupos})
res = res.groupby('grupos')['ids'].apply(np.array).to_frame('ids')
```

Con lo que obtenemos:

> ```
> >>> res
>
>                              ids
> grupos                           
> 0                      [296, 306]
> 1       [160, 161, 365, 386, 471]
> ```

La columna `ids` contiene arrays de NumPy.

Si necesitas más eficiencia hay que bajar un nivel y usar NumPy, ordenando el array usando `grupos` como clave y haciendo slicing.

Comment: Muchas gracias ! 
¿Y como vinculo los ids con los grupos ? 
¿Con la parte `.apply(np.array).to_frame('ids')` ?

Comment: De "vincular" se encarga `groupby`. Por cada grupo crea un array con las ids que le pertenecen (tienen el mismo grupo). `to_frame('ids')` es solo para pasar de una serie (que es lo que retorna `groupby`) a un dataframe y nombrar la columna `ids`. Puedes acceder a las `ids` de cada grupo por índice (`res.loc[0]['ids']`), iterar sobre el dataframe, o pasarlo a un diccionario (`res.to_dict()['ids']`).  Saludos.